# QFile and FileRef for the same file

Tags: qt, taglib

I have a little problem with my Qt program.
There is a function which downloads a mp3 file (using QFile) and is called each time new datas are available to be written.
Once these datas have been written, I 'd like to construct a TagLib::FileRef variable, to read the bitrate of the file. The problem is this variable is always null, because the file is already opened.
How can I process, without having to close and re-open the file each time ?

Thanks

Comment: Downgrading to taglib 1.7.2 have fixed the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The data might not be written immediately by `QFile` to disk, so another file descriptor open on the same file wouldn't be able to read it.

Try to call `QFile::flush()` after each write.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seems to fix the problem :(